# Very Basic Query on Java Array processing

Tags: java, arrays, loops

Trying to self teach Java here, so am complete beginner.

Im trying to select and print only multiples of 10 from an array.

Its surely simple if you know how?

Thanks for any help you can give....!

On a side note do you think that a glass of whiskey might be necessary to help me through learning this??

My (very dodgy) code is:

```
    //Print only multiples of 10 in the array

    double Dangermouse[] = { 1,2,4,8,16,32,64,128,256,512 };
    double total = 0;

    if (total %10 = 0)
    {
        for (double x : Dangermouse)
        {
            total = x;
        }
    }

    System.out.println (total);
```

DANGERMOUSE

Comment: Glass of whisky might not do but some study sure can.

Comment: 1) There are no multiples of 10 in your array!?? 2) Never post this sort of question without showing at least ***some*** attempt. Otherwise you're cheating yourself out of a valuable learning experience and us out of knowing what you could be doing wrong and what you need help with. 3) Don't use a for-each loop, but rather a standard for loop with an index if you want to print every 10th number (if your array were that big).

Comment: Just figured that!! Thanks. Wow that was a quick response

Comment: (Prepares stiff whiskey)

Comment: What are you doing? why do you have if statement outside for. You need to loop through and then test in the loop.

Comment: you're also using the assignment operator in the if statement

Comment: Believe it or not Ive just learned a bit. Sorry for a silly question dude

Comment: double Dangermouse[] = { 10,20,4,8,16,32,64,128,256,512 };

Comment: Yep! Really not sure what Im doing in faireness Ouney and Hovercraft Full of Eels.  Im sure that was obvious tho! Not sure how to loop through and test in loop

Comment: Hi Katana24. Guess im trying to run a loop if I get a number divisable by 10. It kinda makes sense in my head but clearly not in Java!

Comment: Im clearly an idiot but believe it or not im working hard on this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should stop drinking whisky while coding.

```
for (int i = 0; i < Dangermouse.length; i++) {
    if (Dangermouse[i] % 10 == 0) {
        System.out.println(Dangermouse[i]);
    }
}
```

Loop goes through the array. If statement checks the current array member if its a multiple of 10. If it is print it and move to the next element in the array and repeat until you run out of the array.

Comment: Thanks so much! Thats given me a pathway when I was lost. So to speak. Cheers!

Comment: Usually dont do the whiskey thing while coding but its Friday night here